# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (274, 1) deep learning

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

this is my code with error

```
def createModel():   
model = Sequential()
# first set of CONV => RELU => MAX POOL layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
# returns our fully constructed deep learning + Keras image classifier 
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
# use binary_crossentropy if there are two classes
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
return model
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_19_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (274, 1)

Comment: print("Reshaping trainX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))
#print(trainX.sample()) 
print(type(trainX)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(trainX.shape) # (750,)
from numpy import zeros
Xtrain = np.zeros([trainX.shape[0],HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH])
for i in range(trainX.shape[0]): # 0 to traindf Size -1
    Xtrain[i] = trainX[i]
print(Xtrain.shape) # (750,128,128,3)
print("Reshaped trainX at..."+ str(datetime.now()))

Comment: print("compiling model...")
sys.stdout.flush()
model = createModel()

# print the summary of model
from keras.utils import print_summary
print_summary(model, line_length=None, positions=None, print_fn=None)

# add some visualization
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))

Comment: print("training network...")

sys.stdout.flush()
#class_mode ='categorical', # 2D one-hot encoded labels
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(Xtrain, trainY, batch_size=BS), \
    validation_data=(valX, valY), \
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, \
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

# save the model to disk
print("Saving model to disk")
sys.stdout.flush()
model.save("/tmp/mymodel")

Comment: Highlighted error